# unity c# json not working

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to c# and unity. I am attempting to get variables from my json files but the program seems to only return booleans and strings properly.

c#

```
public class Reputation
{
    public int normal { get; set; }
}
void Start()
{
    string reputation = @"c:\path\to\file\reputation.json";
    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader (reputation); 
    player.reputation = JsonUtility.FromJson<Reputation>(reader2.ReadToEnd ());
    reader.Close ();
    Debug.Log(player.reputation.normal);
}
```

json

```
{
    "normal":20
}
```

and the log displays a 0

Comment: See *"4.TROUBLESHOOTING JsonUtility:" from the answer in the duplicate. I can spot few issues already such as the use of `{ get; set; }` and no presence of `[Serializable]`. There may be other issues in your code.

Comment: removing {get; set;} worked, but i figured i should let you know that 
"The type or namespace name `serializable' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: It's `Serializable` not `serializable` and you must import `System` namespace or use `System.Serializable` directly.